# lambda not updating DynamoDB data on first run but updates on second run

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda function which is updating data in DynamoDB table(Based on specific user properties I want to change some values for that user.). When It gets executed first time then it doesn't work, but on second execution it updates the data. It works alternatively. one time it updates and one time it doesn't. What could be the reason for this.

Based on specific user properties I want to change some values for that user.

Comment: Could it be a read consistency issue (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html)? More details on how you've set up the table and some code are needed.

Comment: Indeed we need to see some code and some concrete examples of what you have tried to do in order to help diagnose the problem

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a syntax error while using or not using `await` and `.promise()`

Also out of experience there occur problems like you described it when you call it like this:

```
await nameOfDb.update(params, function (err, data) {   
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);   
      else     console.log(data); 
}).promise();
```

which is the recommended way to call `.update()` in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html)

so I prefer using

```
Try {
    await nameOfDb.update(params).promise();
} 
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

which always works as I want it to work when using `.update()`